# Points lying on more than one irreducible component

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$.  Let $X = X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_n$ be its decomposition into irreducible components.  If a point $x \in X$ lies in more than one component, is it necessarily singular? Why?

Answer (score 9):

Let me assume that $X$ is locally Noetherian; otherwise, I don't know what the word “singular” means. The minimal primes of the local ring $\mathcal O_{X, x}$ correspond to the irreducible components of $X$ passing through $x$. If there is more than one of these then $\mathcal O_{X, x}$ is certainly not a domain, and it is a fact that [regular local rings are domains](http://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Regular_local_ring_implies_integral_domain).

Comment: This never seemed obvious to me from the definition, but I'm glad that it's true.

Comment: I second that, really nice answer!